# Where is the "Sync Project With Gradle Files" option in Android Studio 3.5.3?

Tags: android-studio, flutter

I'm new to Android Studio and I'm having trouble in finding the **"Sync Project With Gradle Files"**

option in **Android Studio version 3.5.3**. I'm currently developing applications with Flutter.

I did find out that in the **previous version** of Android Studio (I'm not sure which, sorry!), it seems that the "Sync Project With Gradle Files" option can be found by clicking 
`File > Sync Project With Gradle Files` OR at the toolbar.

(Attached are images regarding previous "Sync Project With Gradle Files" locations)

[File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y4u5b.png)

[toolbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dilje.png)

However, I could not find it in my Android Studio version 3.5.3's  `File` nor at the toolbar. There is no such option.

> I am sorry if this question has already been answered else where or
>   the question is a duplicated one. (This is also my first time posting
>   a question in Stack Overflow) I would be very grateful if someone can
>   help me with this...thank you in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This icon is not showing up because you are inside your Flutter project.

If you open the Android project, that is inside your Flutter project, directly on Android Studio, an Icon will appear next to the AVD Manager (Device Manager) that looks like a little elefant with an arrow pointing diagonally to the bottom left corner. That is the button that does the action "Sync project with Gradle Files".

The first time you open the Android project directly it may take a minute for that icon to not be greyed out, as Android Studio will be syncing all the files, as you'll be able to see on the bottom bar.

Comment: That little elephant seems to have strolled off to his own adventures in Android Studio 2021. I think you have to actually select the build.gradle files for him to appear.

Answer (score 3):

Try first with right click on `build.gradle` and than click on `Import Gradle Project`

Answer (score 2):

If you right click on the `build.gradle` there's a `Synchronize` option nearer to the bottom of the popup. HTH

Comment: Running AndroidStudio 4.2.1 on Catalina but there is no 'Synchronize' option in both app/build.gradle and android/build.gradle files.